# I want the collection view to show 2 columns per row, how do I do that?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SkrapCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

This is my collection view code where I need to place the code to edit the number of columns. It is 6 now.

Comment: Use the following link:-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63071918/collectionview-grid-layout-issue-with-different-devices/63079009#63079009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not check the device size because we can use the collectionView width to calculate the width of the cell. Using the cell width you can calculate the height as per your need.

One more thing: You need to use **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** & confirm the delegate & implement method below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let padding: CGFloat =  25
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 115)
}
```

Comment: Are you using custom cells or cells inside the storyboard?

Comment: inside the storyboard with a cell class

Comment: What is the size of the cell?

Comment: 161 x 115 (width x height)

Comment: Updated the answer please try now. Also, did you confirmed the delegate http://prntscr.com/tqh7z8 like this?

Comment: @Anan Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54703798/10150796 it's working for Swift 4 & 5 All devices

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a collection view from the storyboard then maybe this solution can work for you

```
class AbcViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    coachCollectionView.dataSource = self
    coachCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = AbcViewController.createLayout()

    
}
static func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
    
    
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize:
        NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(2/5)),
        subitem: item,
        count: 2
    )
    
    
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}}
```